# Create login session in django

Tags: python, django

so i try to make a login  with session , so user must logged in first before redirect to another page , so i think im doing right , but i dont know how to check if i save the session or not , here's the code

views.py

```
def login_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':         
        form = AuthenticationForm(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():           
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            password = form.cleaned_data.get('password')
            guess = User.objects.get(username=username)
            identity = guess.id 
            table2 = UserProfileInfo.objects.get(user_id=identity)
            role = table2.role                                               
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)  
            if user is not None: 
                if role == 'Business Analyst':
                    request.session['username'] = username
                    login(request, user)
                    return render(request,'index.html',{"username":username})
                elif role == 'Admin':
                    login(request, user)
                    return redirect('/manageuser/')
                elif role == 'Manager':
                    login(request, user)
                    return redirect('/approvallist/')
                elif role == 'Segment Manager':
                    login(request, user)
                    return redirect('/approvallist/')
            else:
                messages.error(request, "Invalid username or password!")
        else:
            messages.error(request, "Invalid username or password!")
    form = AuthenticationForm()
    return render(request,"login.html",{"form":form})

def index_view(request):
    if request.session.has_key('username'):
        username = request.session['username']
        print(username)
        return render(request, 'index.html',{"username":username})
```

settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'polls.apps.PollsConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

SESSION_ENGINE = "django.contrib.sessions.backends.cache"
```

When i try to print the username , it wont show in command prompt , i thought i already save the  request.session['username'] in the username variable

and when i try to restart the server and try to redirect to /home without log in , it show error `'The view didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead'`

P.S : im trying for role business analyst first , if it works , i will apply to another role
anyone can help find the errors? im stuck here .. Thankyouu <3

Comment: Django has a user management with roles already, why the reimplementation?

Comment: @KlausD. first mybad about it , its my friends that use the reimplementation role in new table when make make the registration module ..  but does it affect the session module in django?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways by which you can check whether the user session exists or not .
1) In your browser do inspect elements and then go to the storage where you will be able   to see that a session id is created have the user logs in.

2) request.user/request.session will indicate you if user has authenticated or not.